# Accessing Azure VM Role by Remote Desktop

Tags: azure

I followed the instruction [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_vmrolelab_topic3) to set up and deploy a VM Role onto Azure. It all worked fine.

But I cannot RDP onto it.

If you check the link above, after I click 'Connect' in step 4, it remains busy and never goes into step 5.

This error (check screenshot below) arises every single time. Any tips/help/ideas?
[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Do you have another network you can try it on? A firewall could be blocking your RDP port (3389).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on above screenshot your virtual machine **whatever.cloudapp.net** is not accessible. It is possible that:

1. Virtual machine is not running and because of that the machine is not available
2. Virtual machine is running but met some problem and because of Remote Connection services is not running and you can not connect
3. You are trying to connect to Virtual machine incorrectly because your screenshot tells that  you have either created a RDP file to connect or trying to connect directly by creating a new connection.

If you are sure that your Azure Virtual machine is running properly, then I believe #3 is your main problem. This is because the RDP access script which you download from your own portal has some cookie info which is needed to connect to your Virtual machine.

The best would be to download the RDP access script directly from your Portal related to your Virtual Machine instance and then try to connect it.

If you need help, please follow my [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/04/03/how-to-login-into-windows-azure-virtual-machine-using-remote-desktop.aspx) which will guide you step by step on this regard.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it was #2 of your suspicions and I had not enabled RDP on the VM.

Answer (score 1):

You can't connect to your instance directly. The load balancer needs some extra information to make the connection possible (to which instance you need to connect). Try going through the portal and pressing the **Connect** button on one of your instances:

[image]

If you open the file with notepad, you'll see the extra information that will be sent to the load balancer.

Comment: Hi, yes I have done that, after that only the RDP gives the error (in the screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

Have you provided the port number as well in the RDP connection?

In my case it was port 59104. Thus in the computer field, you need to enter:

```
whatevermachinename.cloudapp.net:59104
```